Trouble fetching nested classes with Hibernate
I have the following classes:
@Entity
@Table(name = "grandparents")
public class Grandparent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "grandparent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Parent> parents;

    public Grandparent() {}

    public Grandparent(String name, List<Parent> parents) {
        this.name = name;
        this.parents = parents;
        for (Parent parent : parents) {
            parent.setGrandparent(this); // Maintain bi-directional relationship
        }
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Parent> getParents() {
        return parents;
    }

    public void setParents(List<Parent> parents) {
        this.parents = parents;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "parents")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Child> children;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "grandparent_id")
    private Grandparent grandparent;

    public Parent() {}

    public Parent(String name, List<Child> children) {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = children;
        for (Child child : children) {
            child.setParent(this); // Ensure bi-directional relationship is maintained
        }
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public Grandparent getGrandparent() {
        return grandparent;
    }

    public void setGrandparent(Grandparent grandparent) {
        this.grandparent = grandparent;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "children")
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    @ElementCollection()
    @CollectionTable(name = "CONTENT-OPTIONS",  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD-ID"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "OPTION-KEY")
    @Column(name = "OPTION-VALUE")
    private Map<String, String> contentOptions = new HashMap<>();

    public Child() {}

    public Child(String name, Map<String, String> contentOptions) {
        this.name = name;
        this.contentOptions = contentOptions;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getContentOptions() {
        return contentOptions;
    }

    public void setContentOptions(Map<String, String> contentOptions) {
        this.contentOptions = contentOptions;
    }
}

I want to fetch a Grandparent with all his parents and their children and their contentOptions. What would be the way to do that with Hibernate 6 using FetchType.Lazy?
I tried the following things:

Obviously one way to do it would be to use FetchType.Eager, but that seems to defeat the purpose in my eyes. Cause I don't want to always fetch everything. But this would work

I tried using Set<> for my relations, but this just swallows the problem according to this link (Hibernate throws MultipleBagFetchException - cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags)

I tried to use join fetch, but this is not possible with multiple Entities. If I try to do that, I get a MultipleBagFetchException. Then I tried the solution from the link above, but this seems impractical. Also now I don't really know how to fetch the rest in a good way. As you can see here:
public Grandparent findById(Integer id) {
    try (EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()) {
        Grandparent grandparent = entityManager.createQuery("""
            SELECT gp FROM Grandparent gp
            JOIN FETCH gp.parents p
            WHERE gp.id = :id
        """, Grandparent.class).setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();

        grandparent.setParents(entityManager.createQuery("""
            SELECT p FROM Parent p
             JOIN FETCH p.children c
             WHERE p in :parents
         """, Parent.class).setParameter("parents", grandparent.getParents()).getResultList());


        return grandparent;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}



Is there another way to fetch these entities while using FetchType.lazy?
